# Updating Memo/Rich Text Editor Fields with the API

Tags: api, html

I have in my CiviCRM a custom field which is a memo field with a text editor. If I update the contents of this field through the user interface contents is saved correctly as html. E.g. `<p>Hello world</p>`

However when I use the api (for example through the api explorer) the html gets malformed. Entering the same html results in the following: `&gt;&lt;Hello world&gt;/p&lt;`

How do I update the contents of a custom field which should html code?

Update: I disocvered there is an API Wrapper in place which encodes the html input. This wrapper gets executed for every api call. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/API/HTMLInputCoder.php#L147

Thanks,
Jaap Jansma

Comment: Aren't custom fields in `getSkipFields`? What kind of API call are you using? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a contact custom field with data type "Note" and field type "RichTextEditor" and then ran this API call:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {
  "contact_type": "Individual",
  "id": 180,
  "custom_15": "<p><strong>foobar</strong></p>"
});
```

The value was stored as-is, and shows correctly in the UI.

[This part](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/35e93e6ad119df822d538bed2a7d80cb3492d589/CRM/Utils/API/HTMLInputCoder.php#L123-L126) of `CRM_Utils_API_HTMLInputCoder` should ensure that custom fields of type `RichTextEditor` are excluded.

One scenario in which this might not work: Let's say you have another API wrapper that renames a parameter from, say, `food_preference` to `custom_22`. If the renaming API wrapper runs *after* `CRM_Utils_API_HTMLInputCoder` (not sure what the order is there, I'd guess core ones run first), `food_preference` would already be encoded before it gets to your wrapper.

Comment: Thanks pfigel! As I read it correctly your answer works from CiviCRM version 5.13.4 and newer. My question was related to CiviCRM 5.4.